# Xpath / choose all xpath with attribute that start with pattern. except some

Tags: xpath

I want to get all `xpath` which start with `ng`, except `ng-repeat` and `ng-class`.

I tried the following:

`//div[@class="model"]/descendant-or-self::*[@*[starts-with(local-name(),'ng')] and (local-name() !='ng-repeat') and (local-name() !='ng-class')]`

But I still get all element which start with `ng`, also element just with `ng-class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
div[@class="model"]/descendant-or-self::*[@*[starts-with(local-name(),'ng')]][@*[local-name() !='ng-repeat']][@*[local-name()!='ng-class']]
```